# SSIS "Save Copy of ..." missing in my Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

When trying to save my SSIS packages from my vs 2008 to my sql 2008 server.  I've lost the option to "Save Copy of Package.dtsx".  I have to do some crazy work around that I can't remember ever!

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are not debugging first.  If it is still missing...

In Visual Studio...

- Go to Tools > Customize.
- Go to the 'Commands' Tab.
- Highlight 'File' in the left pane.
- Find the 'Save Copy of Package As...' item.
- Drag that into your File menu.

Hopefully that will get you saving again!